# Проверка подключения к интернету

Tags: c#

Нужен код который будет проверять подключение к интернету, если true то действия программы продолжаются, а если false то действия программы останавливаются. Находил много кодов, но если подключена локальная сеть то они показывали true.

Answer (score 5):

Все примеры шли наверно с применением функции `InternetGetConnectedState`, которая возвращает `true`  даже если установлено LAN соединение. Но у нее есть флаги, которое будет содержать описание соединения.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class InternetCS
{        
    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    private extern static bool InternetGetConnectedState( out int Description, int ReservedValue );

    public static bool IsConnectedToInternet( )
    {
        int Desc ;
        return InternetGetConnectedState( out Desc, 0 ) ;
    }
}
```

В Desc как раз содержится описание, значения можно посмотреть [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384702(VS.85).aspx).
Пара примеров:

```
INTERNET_CONNECTION_LAN 
  0x02
INTERNET_CONNECTION_MODEM
  0x01
```

Тут вопрос теперь такой, что будет содержаться в `Desc` если существует и LAN  и доступ в интернет?
Пробуйте, и тестируйте.

Второй вариант проще, просто пытаемся послать запрос к сайту:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
String Response;
Response = Client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```

и проверить ответ. Но тут,  конечно зависит от сайта, который укажите, а вдруг он упал?
Хотя, windows вроде как, проверяет доступ к интернету путем пинга сайта microsoft.com.

Так же, у гугла есть DNS сервер. По адресу: 8.8.8.8. Поэтому мой вариант пинговать этот адрес и все.

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с Windows Vista в системе есть инструмент для проверки интернет-соединения. Это [Network Awareness on Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697388(VS.85).aspx). Вы можете использовать тот же механизм в приложении на C#.

```
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public static class ConnectivityChecker
{
    public enum ConnectionStatus
    {
        NotConnected,
        LimitedAccess,
        Connected
    }

    public static ConnectionStatus CheckInternet()
    {
        // Проверить подключение к dns.msftncsi.com
        try 
        {
            IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry("dns.msftncsi.com");
            if (entry.AddressList.Length == 0)
            {
                return ConnectionStatus.NotConnected;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!entry.AddressList[0].ToString().Equals("131.107.255.255"))
                {
                    return ConnectionStatus.LimitedAccess;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return ConnectionStatus.NotConnected;
        }

        // Проверить загрузку документа ncsi.txt
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt");
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (responce.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return ConnectionStatus.LimitedAccess;
            }
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responce.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                if (sr.ReadToEnd().Equals("Microsoft NCSI"))
                {
                    return ConnectionStatus.Connected;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ConnectionStatus.LimitedAccess;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return ConnectionStatus.NotConnected;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool inet_connect()
{
    int fsockopen;
    char ip[15] = "46.182.85.8";
    int port = "80";
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    WSADATA WsaData;
    if (int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (sock == -1) {
        return false;

    }

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

    fsockopen = connect(sock, (sockaddr *) & addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (fsockopen != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Тебе понадобится библиотека winsock.h или winsock2.h а также подключи библиотеку ws2_32.lib. Какой у тебя компилятор?

Comment: по-моему стоит метка [C#](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/c%23/)